# NestJS + Vite + Graphql, playground loads once but then immediately throws "Schema must contain uniquely named type" reproducible git repo inside

Tags: node.js, nestjs, vite, nestjs-graphql

I've been trying to get this combination working for a while and fiddled with versions & compatibilities issue until I've hit this brick wall.

The app works in production once you build it -- it appears to solely be a vite issue when running in development mode.

I've created a minium repository where the issue is reproducible: https://github.com/sebastiangug/nest-graphql-vite

The graphql configuration:

```
        const config: ApolloDriverConfig = {
          debug: true,
          playground: true,
          autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql',
          sortSchema: true,
          path: "/graphql",
          cors: {
            origin: ['*'],
          },
        };
```

Even if the request is not Graphql related, when the second HTTP request hits the server, vite attempts to do something that causes that schema error.

This seems to be a problem unique to this combination of tools.

Comment: How was it so far?

Comment: How was what? it was fine with the exception above.

Comment: @SebastianG did you resolve it?

Comment: @FooBar yes -- it doesn't do that with the latest versions of everything (nestjs and vite plugin)